# IE 8, function failing to link to input button

Tags: javascript, function, button, input, internet-explorer-8

I'm creating a button input on the fly with "document.createElement('input')". The button generates fine in all browsers, but the function does not fire in IE 8 (or IE 7) as it does in all other browsers.  I tested the code of the function being called in IE 7 & 8 and it works. Does anyone know a way around this browser issue?
Thanks for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


function killWindow(){

window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close(); 

}

document.observe("dom:loaded",function(){
 var forceCloseButton = document.createElement("input");
 forceCloseButton.setAttribute("id","forceClose");
 forceCloseButton.setAttribute("type","image");
 forceCloseButton.setAttribute("src","SurveyResource/Button-Close");
 forceCloseButton.setAttribute("class","button");
 forceCloseButton.setAttribute("onclick","killWindow()");

 var a=$('datstat_bottomcenterbuttons');
a.appendChild(forceCloseButton);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never never set an event handler with `setAttribute`.

You need to use `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` or set `onclick` directly.

Also setting class is going to have issues, look at className.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I'll make some changes and test it out.

Comment: I changed 'forceCloseButton.setAttribute("onclick","killWindow()");' to 'forceCloseButton.onclick=killWindow;' and it is now working in IE8. Thanks again.